Undefined reference using stringResource in a Kotlin-multiplatform desktop app
I'm new to Kotlin and I wanted to start a project for a Desktop application.
To do it I initially used the multiplatform wizard.
Now, I want to add multilanguage support to my simple application and I found some tutorials for creating the strings.xml file.
I created it in a new folder located in composeApp/src/commonMain/composeResources/values which is at the same level of the wizard default created composeApp/src/commonMain/composeResources/drawable.
My xml looks like:
<resources>
    <string name="no_ports">No ports available.</string>
</resources>

When I try to run my application
package org.openswim

import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.jetbrains.compose.resources.stringResource
import org.jetbrains.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.fazecast.jSerialComm.SerialPort

import openswim.composeapp.generated.resources.Res
import openswim.composeapp.generated.resources.compose_multiplatform

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        var showContent by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        var ports by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyArray<SerialPort>()) }

        // Start a coroutine to fetch ports
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                while (true) {
                    ports = SerialPort.getCommPorts()
                    delay(500) // Fetch every 0.5 seconds
                }
            }
        }

        Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Button(onClick = { showContent = !showContent }) {
                Text("Show ports")
            }
            AnimatedVisibility(showContent) {
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                    Text("Available Serial Ports:")
                    if (ports.isEmpty()) {
                        Text(stringResource(Res.string.no_ports))
                    } else {
                        ports.forEach { port ->
                            Text("Name: ${port.getSystemPortName()}, Baud Rate: ${port.getBaudRate()}, Description: ${port.getPortDescription()}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I got this error:
Unresolved reference 'no_ports'.

but I'm not able to understand what's missing.
EDIT: I upload also my build.gradle.kts file
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
}

kotlin {
    jvm("desktop")
    
    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting
        val exposedVersion: String by project
        
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel)
            implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.swing)
            // Serial Communication - jSerialComm
            implementation(libs.jSerialComm)
            // Database - Exposed
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-crypt:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-dao:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-kotlin-datetime:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-json:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-money:$exposedVersion")
            implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-spring-boot-starter:$exposedVersion")
        }
    }
}


compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "org.openswim.MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "OpenSwim"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
            licenseFile.set(project.file("../LICENSE"))
        }
    }
}


In the build.gradle.kts file in the composeApp directory, add a dependency to the commonMain source set
kotlin {
sourceSets {
    commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation(compose.components.resources)
    }
  }
}

Create a new directory composeResources in the source set directory.

Organize the composeResources directory structure according to these
rules:
Images should be in the drawable directory.
Fonts should be in the font directory.
Strings should be in the values directory.
Other files should be in the files directory, with any folder
hierarchy you may find appropriate.


more details refer Setup and configuration for multiplatform resources
In Addition
In the compose.resources {} block of the build.gradle.kts file, you can specify several settings that affect the way the Res class is generated for your project. An example configuration looks like this:
compose.resources {
publicResClass = false
packageOfResClass = "me.sample.library.resources"
generateResClass = auto
}

Store all string resources in XML files in composeResources/values directories. A static accessor is generated for each item in each file.Refer Using multiplatform resources in your app

Thanks for the answer but I've already followed the tutorial... I've uploaded the build.gradle.kts file in the question if you need it

please check the updated answer

By default, Compose Multiplatform assigns the {group name}.{module name}.generated.resources package to the class, so I didn't add this. However, also adding these lines lead to Undefined reference...

Edit: by doing an import openswim.composeapp.generated.resources.* it works... what's the package inside resources that I'm missing?
